# Match particular CDATA sections in XML data

Tags: regex, xml, powershell, powershell-3.0, cdata

I am trying to do a PowerShell Regex, I have the following page (further below) that I want to do a match from, the two parts in bold is the information that I want to capture and assign to a variable. So I need two regex's. From the text below, the two area's I need to find exactly are **King** and **Years & Years**. Please note, these two areas change (hence the reason I need to capture them), the rest of of the code stays the same.

This is the regex I have at the moment, but it's not working for me.

```
\s+artist\s*>\s*<\s*!\s*[CDATA\s*[(.*)\s*]\s*]\s*>\s*<\s*/artist
```

And here is the page (or data) I am trying to use regex with.

```xml
<on_air>
  <publishedInfo publishedDate="2015-07-18 16:24:28" />
  <stationName><![CDATA[Mix 106.5]]></stationName>
  <stationPrefix><![CDATA[mix1065]]></stationPrefix>
  <generic_coverart><![CDATA[http://media.arn.com.au/images/getImage.aspx?i=generic_mix1065.jpg]]></generic_coverart>
  <now_playing>
    <audio ID="id_1705168034_30458146" type="song">
      <title generic="False"><![CDATA[King*]]></title>
      <artist><![CDATA[Years & Years]]></artist>
      <number><![CDATA[46029]]></number>
      <cut><![CDATA[1]]></cut>
      <ref><![CDATA[]]></ref>
      <played_datetime><![CDATA[2015-07-18 16:24:27]]></played_datetime>
      <length><![CDATA[00:03:28]]></length>
      <coverart generic="true"><![CDATA[http://media.arn.com.au/images/getImage.aspx?i=generic_mix1065.jpg]]></coverart>
      <options>
        <option><![CDATA[KIIS S Integrated]]></option>
      </options>
    </audio>
  </now_playing>
```

Answer (score 4):

If it is a valid XML, then you does not need to use regular expressions. PowerShell adapt XML objects and you can use standard property syntax to navigate on them:

```
$xml=[xml]@'
<on_air>
  <publishedInfo publishedDate="2015-07-18 16:24:28" />
  <stationName><![CDATA[Mix 106.5]]></stationName>
  <stationPrefix><![CDATA[mix1065]]></stationPrefix>
  <generic_coverart><![CDATA[http://media.arn.com.au/images/getImage.aspx?i=generic_mix1065.jpg]]></generic_coverart>
  <now_playing>
    <audio ID="id_1705168034_30458146" type="song">
      <title generic="False"><![CDATA[King*]]></title>
      <artist><![CDATA[Years & Years]]></artist>
      <number><![CDATA[46029]]></number>
      <cut><![CDATA[1]]></cut>
      <ref><![CDATA[]]></ref>
      <played_datetime><![CDATA[2015-07-18 16:24:27]]></played_datetime>
      <length><![CDATA[00:03:28]]></length>
      <coverart generic="true"><![CDATA[http://media.arn.com.au/images/getImage.aspx?i=generic_mix1065.jpg]]></coverart>
      <options>
        <option><![CDATA[KIIS S Integrated]]></option>
      </options>
    </audio>
  </now_playing>
</on_air>
'@
$xml.on_air.now_playing.audio.title.'#cdata-section'
$xml.on_air.now_playing.audio.artist.'#cdata-section'
```

Comment: Hi PetSerAl, can I please give you the who URI - **http://media.arn.com.au/xml/mix1011_now.xml** this is XML already, based on this URI, can you please give me a way to export the Artist & Title and apply to a variable (one variable for each the artist & title). I think I need to use Invoke-WebRequest

Comment: To load XML you can use this: `$xml=New-Object xml;$xml.Load('http://media.arn.com.au/xml/mix1011_now.xml')`. Than you can navigate on it in a way, that I show in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You want to escape bracket literals.

Also, it's a good practice to avoid using the dot "match almost any character" metacharacter when your intentions are more specific.  In your case, what you really want to do is match until you hit the closing bracket, so it's safer to specify that:

```
'\s+artist\s*>\s*<\s*!\s*\[CDATA\s*\[([^]]*)\s*\]\s*\]\s*>\s*<\s*\/artist'
```

Note:  Regex is contextual, so the reason I don't have to escape the closing bracket within the character class is because of its position, i.e., being the first character specified in the negated class--in that context, it cannot be the closing bracket for the character class.  In other words, it's not ambiguous.

Comment: Thank you... and thanks for the explanation. I'll read that a few times for it to soak in.

Comment: Sure, so `\[` is the literal bracket; `(` begins the capture group, but instead of `.*` it's safer to capture until the closing right bracket `[^]]`.  To illustrate the danger of using dot when not necessary, if you had: `<artist><![CDATA[Years & Years]]></artist><artist2><![CDATA][blah]]></artist2>`, your `(.*)` would capture from the first "Years" through "blah," whereas `([^]]*)` would not.  BTW, in both our regexes, the trailing `\s*` is useless. To avoid capturing the spaces before ']', look at zero-length assertions if PowerShell supports them.  `...\[CDATA\s*\[((?:(?!\s*\]).)*)`

Answer (score 0):

To help get off the ground, here is a suggestion for y&y (insert whitespace-selector whereever possible):

```
artist><!\[CDATA\[Years & Years\]\]></artist
```